# .NET listview programmatically change height

Tags: .net, listview

Is it possible to programmatically change the height of a `ListView` as you add items?

Basically I would like the `ListView` to `AutoSize` the height.

I've tried:

```
lv.Height = myValue;
```

And:

```
lv.UpdateBounds(x, y, newWidth, newHeight);
```

Neither of these seems to update what the control looks like on the form though.

**Edit:**

This listview is actually a user control where I've inherited a `ListView`. I'm trying to change the height in the constructor to make the items that I pull in using reflection all appear.

Comment: The standard bug here is that you are using the wrong reference.  Typically one for a form that you created but never displayed instead of the one that the user is looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are adding item to listview on button click then for every new item added increase the size of your listview by 5px ? or any size that you want it to grow too..

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add("Hello How are you");
        listView1.Height = listView1.Height + 5;
    }
```